# C#.NET WebService returning object

Tags: c#, web-services

I am creating a Web Service using ASP.NET C#. I am sending various data types from the webservice so I use the following structure.

```
public enum WS_ServiceResponseResult
{
    Success,
    Failure,
}
public class WS_ServiceResponse
{
    public WS_ServiceResponseResult result { get; set; }
    public object data { get; set; }
}

public class WS_User
{
    public long id{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

Webservice Sample Method

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public WS_ServiceResponse LogIn(string username, string pasword)
    {
        WS_ServiceResponse osr = new WS_ServiceResponse();
        long userID = UserController.checkLogin(username, pasword);

        if (userID != 0)
        {
            osr.result = WS_ServiceResponseResult.Success;
            osr.data = new WS_User() { id = userID, name = username };
        }
        else
        {
            osr.result = WS_ServiceResponseResult.Failure;
            osr.data = "Invalid username/password!";
        }
        return osr;
    }
```

I am using two client types, javascript and C#.NET Windows Form. When I call from javascript I get no problem and the osr.data is filled with WS_User. So i can use osr.data.id easily. But when I use from C#.NET (proxy is generated using "Add Web Reference") I can successfully call but when the result arrives I get a Soap Exception

> {System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Server was unable to process request.
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML
>   document. ... ...

What am I missing? I Guess object is not well defined and causing the problems. What are the workarounds?

Thanks

Maksud

Addition:

If add the following dummy method, then it works nicely. Hope it helps, to get the solution.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public WS_User Dummy()
    {
        return new WS_User();
    }
```

Comment: Do you generate proxy client for C#?

Comment: Yes. I used Add Web Reference to do that. If I return osr.data = "abcd";// that is object is data then I get no exception. I gets result= success and data="abcd"; But if I use WS_User object then I gets into trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar Problem returning an "object" (multiple classes possible)
Here is a sample code:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Object")]
public sealed class XMLObject
{

    private Object _Object;

    [XmlElement(Type=typeof(App.Projekte.Projekt), ElementName="Projekt")]
    [XmlElement(Type=typeof(App.Projekte.Task), ElementName="Task")]
    [XmlElement(Type=typeof(App.Projekte.Mitarbeiter), ElementName="Mitarbeiter")]
    public Object Object
    {
        get
        {
            return _Object;
        }
        set
        {
            _Object = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I think you should change your code this way:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="ServiceResponse")]
public class WS_ServiceResponse
{
    public WS_ServiceResponseResult result { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Type=typeof(WS_User), ElementName="WS_User")]
    [XmlElement(Type=typeof(string), ElementName="Text")]
    public object data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. And if I needed some array then 
[XmlElement(Type=typeof(WS_User[]), ElementName="WS_User[]")] is also working. WoW.

Comment: Do we need change "public object data { get; set; }"

Comment: Although this solution works, my concern is that you would have to manually add XmlElement attributes as more primitive and referenced types use this object.

Is there a cleaner approach to this?