# ASMX WebService returning XmlNode instead of custom object

Tags: asp.net, object, serialization, asmx, xmlnode

Here is the webservice:

Custom classes:

```cs
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
    }
    public B prop { get; set; } 
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
    }
    public A prop { get; set; }
}
```

Webmethod:

```cs
[WebMethod]
[XmlInclude(typeof(A))]
public object Test()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.prop = new B();

    return a;
}
```

Here is the client side:

```cs
Service ws = new Service();
var response = ws.Test();
```

So, why is the webservice returning XmlNode list instead of class A? How to solve it?

PS: if I comment `public A prop { get; set; }` line, it works

Comment: FYI, the `[Serializable]` attribute is not used by XML Serialization.

Comment: Alright, removed. Any ideas how to solve this loop serialization problem?

Comment: There is no problem. You told it to return `object`, so it's returning the most general possible type. If you didn't mean `object`, then don't return `object`.

Comment: The main point here is that if I comment `public A prop { get; set; }` it will return A as expected. How to achieve this without commenting code line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the solution:

I could use a wrapper, like this:

- [C#.NET WebService returning object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599063/c-net-webservice-returning-object)

Or I use the [return:] attribute, like this:

```cs
[WebMethod]
[return: XmlElement(typeof(A))]
public object Test()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.prop = new B();

    return a;
}
```

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/599ed74a-ad3d-451e-9a41-551900c542da/

About attribute targets:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3787ac0(v=vs.80).aspx